# Maui creating multiple buttons with a list

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to make multiple buttons (add and remove) which both use a counter to add a number. The amount of buttons depends on how many people are in the list, they should also be different for every person.

My main problem is getting all the buttons instead of just the last one made, I am also expecting that the counter will use every button instead of the button designed for that counter.

This is my first time using MAUI and I can't seem to find anything to help me with my problem.

```cs
private void CreateButton()
{
    string names = "1;2;3";
    var list = names.ToString().Split(';');
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Label lblName = new Label { Text = list[i].ToString() };
        var counter = 0;
        Label lblCounter = new Label
        {
            Text = $": {counter}",            
        };
        Button btnAdd = new Button
        {
            Text = $"{list[i]}: add",
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Green,
            BorderColor= Colors.Black,
            Command = new Command
            (
                execute: async() =>
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    lblCounter.Text = $": {counter.ToString()}";
                }
            )
        };
        Button btnRemove = new Button
        {
            Text = $"{list[i]}: remove",
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Red,
            BorderColor = Colors.Black,
            Command = new Command
            (
                execute: async () =>
                {
                    counter -= 1;
                    if (counter <= 0)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    lblCounter.Text = $": {counter.ToString()}";
                }
            )
        };
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                lblName, btnAdd, lblCounter, btnRemove
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the full code for creating the buttons, it only creates the one for number 3.

Comment: every time you loop, you are replacing the old value of `Content` instead of appending

Comment: Yea i eventually realised i replaced it but i don't know how to append to content since .Append or .Add doesn't seem to exist or i am doing something wrong with it.

Comment: `Content` can only contain a single value.  You need to use a container like a StackLayout, and append to that container.  Then when you are finished looping assign `Content` to that container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you set the `Content` of your View or Page *inside* of the loop, which means that you're replacing it with each iteration.

To fix this, you need to `Add()` the items to the `StackLayout.Children` instead of replacing the content with a new one every time:

```cs
private void CreateButton()
{
    string names = "1;2;3";
    var list = names.ToString().Split(';');

    var stackLayout = new StackLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Label lblName = new Label { Text = list[i].ToString() };
        var counter = 0;
        Label lblCounter = new Label
        {
            Text = $": {counter}",            
        };
        Button btnAdd = new Button
        {
            Text = $"{list[i]}: add",
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Green,
            BorderColor= Colors.Black,
            Command = new Command
            (
                execute: async() =>
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    lblCounter.Text = $": {counter.ToString()}";
                }
            )
        };
        Button btnRemove = new Button
        {
            Text = $"{list[i]}: remove",
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Red,
            BorderColor = Colors.Black,
            Command = new Command
            (
                execute: async () =>
                {
                    counter -= 1;
                    if (counter <= 0)
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    lblCounter.Text = $": {counter.ToString()}";
                }
            )
        };

        stackLayout.Children.Add(lblName);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(lblCounter );
        stackLayout.Children.Add(btnAdd);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(btnRemove);
    }

    Content = stackLayout;
}
```

I think you can also directly add items to the `stackLayout` using the `Add()` extension method:

```cs
stackLayout.Add(btnAdd);
```